# array rotation results my array with empty value why is that

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am writing a simple program of array rotation.
when i console log element array , it includes empty along with other values.. why is that and whats the fix?
how can i remove empty ?

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

let num = prompt("Enter Rotation Value : ");

const rotateFunc = (arr, d) => {
  // debugger;
  let result = [];
  let temp = [];
  let element = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i < d) {
      temp[i] = +arr[i];
    } else {
      element[i] = +arr[i];
    }
  }
  console.log(temp);

  console.log(element);

  result = element.concat(temp);
  console.log(result);
};

rotateFunc(arr1, num);
```

results:

temp array console log result:  (3) [1, 2, 3]

element array console log result: (9) [empty × 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

and final result console log : (12) [empty × 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: You're only assigning to `element[i]` when `i >= d`. So all the elements before `d` are empty.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign to an element in the middle of an array, without assigning to the indexes before it, those earlier indexes still exist, they're marked "empty". Since you don't start assigning to `element[i]` until `i` is at least `d`, all the previous elements are empty.

Rather than assigning to specific indexes, use `push()` to append to the arrays starting from the beginning. Then you won't have gaps in the array.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

let num = prompt("Enter Rotation Value : ");

const rotateFunc = (arr, d) => {
  // debugger;
  let result = [];
  let temp = [];
  let element = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i < d) {
      temp.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      element.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  console.log(temp);
  console.log(element);
  result = element.concat(temp);
  console.log(result);
};

rotateFunc(arr1, num);
```

Comment: thank you so much.. i was looking for explaination and you helped me to understand why it is happening. as a beginner i thought "else " part will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update your final array and remove the first `d` elements. You can use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to achieve it. It modifies the array in place

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

let num = prompt("Enter Rotation Value : ");
const rotateFunc = (arr, d) => {
  // debugger;
  let result = [];
  let temp = [];
  let element = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i < d) {
      temp[i] = +arr[i];
    } else {
      element[i] = +arr[i];
    }
  }
   element.splice(0,d);
   console.log(temp);

  console.log(element);

  result = element.concat(temp);

  console.log(result);
  document.write(result);
};

rotateFunc(arr1, num);
```